# When I press back button and reopen my app it goes back to login screen but user is still logged in

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-navigation

When I press back button and reopen my app it goes back to login screen but user is still logged in. I am using navigator.pushandremoveuntill when user signs in and my app works fine until I reopen my app then I am taken back to login page which shouldn't happen as I used navigator.pushandremoveuntill and removed all the background stack screens . can any one help me .

This is my code

```
  signIn() async {
    if (emailController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        passwordController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        passwordController.text.length >= 6) {
      setState(() {
        isClicked = true;
      });
      await FirebaseFunctions()
          .signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text, context);

      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
            (route) => false);
      }
    } else {
      timerSnackbar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          buttonLabel: "",
          context: context,
          contentText: "Please Check your Credentials",
          second: 2,
          afterTimeExecute: () {});
      setState(() {
        isClicked = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

and this is main app

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
          ? const HomeScreen()
          : const SelectionScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SteamBuilder for this purpose.
Just edit the code below depending on your need:

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Firebase',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => directPage(),
      },
    ),
  );
}

class directPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const directPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (_,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return pageOne(); //your page class you want to show when you are logged in. Like showing the welcome page
          }else{
            return pageTwo(); //your page class you want to show when you are not logged in. Like showing the login page
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK automatically persists the user's credentials, and tries to restore them when the app restarts. This requires it to make a call to the server however (for example to check if the account was disabled) which takes a few moments, and during that time `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` will be `null`. During that time your `home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null` runs, and determines correctly that there is no user signed in yet, and renders the `SelectionScreen`.

The solution is to use an [auth state listener](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html), similar to what I show in this article for Android: [Listen for authentication state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android). Since this is a `Stream`, you can wire it up with a `StreamBuilder` in your widget tree, to have your UI respond to any changes in authentication state.

Comment: firebase is not the problem . I am having troubles with flutter navigation specifically pushandremoveuntil which should clear all the screens below the current screen but when I reopen my app after closing it takes me back to a previous screen even though it should have cleared all the screens from the stack.